# AWS lamda code throwing error while executing using firehose

Tags: node.js, aws-lambda

I wrote a node.js code but throwing an error.
Not sure why,maybe need another set of eyes to look.

The functionality of code is parse the data coming through a kinesis stream and filter the data where sector is Retail and add timestamp to data as well.i

The error I am getting is

let match = parser.entry);
^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token )

```
console.log('Loading function');

/* Stock Ticker format parser */
const parser = /^\{\"TICKER_SYMBOL\"\:\"[A-Z]+\"\,\"SECTOR\"\:"[A-Z]+\"\,\"CHANGE\"\:[-.0-9]+\,\"PRICE\"\:[-.0-9]+\}/;

exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {
    let success = 0; // Number of valid entries found
    let failure = 0; // Number of invalid entries found
    let dropped = 0; // Number of dropped entries 

    /* Process the list of records and transform them */
    const output = event.records.map((record) => {

        const entry = (new Buffer(record.data, 'base64')).toString('utf8');
        let match = parser.exec(entry);
        if (match) {
            let parsed_match = JSON.parse(match); 
            var milliseconds = new Date().getTime();
            /* Add timestamp and convert to CSV */
            const result = `${milliseconds},${parsed_match.TICKER_SYMBOL},${parsed_match.SECTOR},${parsed_match.CHANGE},${parsed_match.PRICE}`+"\n";
            const payload = (new Buffer(result, 'utf8')).toString('base64');
            if (parsed_match.SECTOR != 'RETAIL') {
                /* Dropped event, notify and leave the record intact */
                dropped++;
                return {
                    recordId: record.recordId,
                    result: 'Dropped',
                    data: record.data,
                };
            }
            else {
                /* Transformed event */
                success++;  
                return {
                    recordId: record.recordId,
                    result: 'Ok',
                    data: payload,
                };
            }
        }
        else {
            /* Failed event, notify the error and leave the record intact */
            console.log("Failed event : "+ record.data);
            failure++;
            return {
                recordId: record.recordId,
                result: 'ProcessingFailed',
                data: record.data,
            };
        }
        /* This transformation is the "identity" transformation, the data is left intact 
        return {
            recordId: record.recordId,
            result: 'Ok',
            data: record.data,
        } */
    });
    console.log(`Processing completed.  Successful records ${output.length}.`);
    callback(null, { records: output });
};
```

Comment: Make sure that Lambda is actually running your uploaded or saved source code, not some earlier mis-typed version.

Comment: I tried running this code https://www.tutorialspoint.com/execute_nodejs_online.php also but it is throwing error

Comment: Strange. Even basic regex code that uses exec fails at that online site but works fine in local Node v14 and v16.